# JavaFX to Android - Execution failed for task ':deleteSrcAndLayout'

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

good day, I got an issue in creating an android project, Im currently using windows7 with JDK8u40 installed and Im using the latest dalvik sdk. But when I attempted to create an android project, an error was thrown:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':deleteSrcAndLayout'.
> Directory does not exist: C:\AndroidFX\CodeGenerator\src
```

Here's the complete error log:

```
C:\dalvik-sdk\samples\Ensemble8>./gradlew --info createProject -PDEBUG -PDIR=C:/
AndroidFX -PPACKAGE="hello" -PNAME="CodeGenerator" -PANDROID_SDK=C:/AndroidSDK/s
dk -PJFX_SDK=C:/dalvik-sdk -PJFX_APP=C:/Jar -PJFX_MAIN="hello.Hello"
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using empty settings script.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'C:\dalvik-sdk\samples\Ensemble8\
build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'Ensemble8']
Evaluating root project 'Ensemble8' using build file 'C:\dalvik-sdk\samples\Ense
mble8\build.gradle'.
Starting file lock listener thread.
All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'createProject'
Tasks to be executed: [task ':conf', task ':androidCreateProject', task  ':delete
SrcAndLayout', task ':writeAntProperties', task ':updateManifest', task  ':update
StringsXml', task ':updateBuildXml', task ':createProject']
:conf (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:conf
Executing task ':conf' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.

====================================================
Android SDK:            [C:/AndroidSDK/sdk]
Target:                 [android-21]
Project name:           [CodeGenerator]
Package:                [hello]
JavaFX application:     [C:/Jar]
JavaFX sdk:             [C:/dalvik-sdk]
JavaFX main.class:      [hello.Hello]
Workdir:                [C:/AndroidFX]
debug:                  [true]
===================================================

:conf (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.078 secs.
:androidCreateProject (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:androidCreateProject
Executing task ':androidCreateProject' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs)  due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
Starting process 'command 'C:/AndroidSDK/sdk/tools/android.bat''. Working  direct
ory: C:\AndroidFX Command: C:/AndroidSDK/sdk/tools/android.bat create  project -n
 CodeGenerator -p CodeGenerator -t android-21 -k hello -a Activity
An attempt to initialize for well behaving parent process finished.
Successfully started process 'command    'C:/AndroidSDK/sdk/tools/android.bat''
Error: Package name 'hello' contains invalid characters.
A package name must be constitued of two Java identifiers.
Each identifier allowed characters are: a-z A-Z 0-9 _
                                                                         Proces
s 'command 'C:/AndroidSDK/sdk/tools/android.bat'' finished with exit  value 0 (st
ate: SUCCEEDED)
:androidCreateProject (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 1.375 secs.
:deleteSrcAndLayout (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:deleteSrcAndLayout
Executing task ':deleteSrcAndLayout' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
:deleteSrcAndLayout FAILED
:deleteSrcAndLayout (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.594 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\dalvik-sdk\samples\Ensemble8\build.gradle' line: 203

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':deleteSrcAndLayout'.
> Directory does not exist: C:\AndroidFX\CodeGenerator\src

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug  option to
get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Total time: 6.531 secs

Please help me!! Im stuck!!!!
I also tried JDK7u75 but it didnt worked!!

Answer (score 0):

I successfully created an android project by editing the createHelloWorld.bat under android-tools in the dalvik-sdk.